# Is $n^{2} + 5n + 1$ ever an even integer for a chosen natural number n?

Tags: induction

How is it shown that this number is odd for all natural numbers? Can someone show me why this is not an even integer using induction?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If $n$ is even, $n+5$ is odd and conversely. So $n(n+5)=n^2+5n$ is...

Comment: Well if x = even/odd then odd*x = x.  x^2 = x.  And x + x = even.  and $x + 1 = opposite x.  So if n is odd n^2, 5n are odd.  n^2 + 5n is even and n^2 + 5n + 1 is odd.  If n is even n^2, 5n are even.  n^2 + 5n is even and n^2 + 5n + 1 is odd.  But by induction $(n+1)^2 + 5(n+1) + 1 = n^2 + 2n + 1 + 5n + 5 + 1 = n^2 + 5n + 1 + 2n + 6 = n^2 + 5n + 1 + 2(n+3)$.  $2(n+3)$ is even so $n^2 + 5n + 1$ and $(n+1)^2 + 5(n+1) + 1$ have the same parity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $n$ is even then $n^2$ is even $5n$ is even then $n^2+5n+1$ is odd.

If $n$ is odd then $n^2$ is odd $5n$ is odd then $n^2+5n+1$ is odd.

If you really need induction:

**Hint:**

$$(n+1)^2+5(n+1)+1=(n^2+5n+1)+(2n+6)$$

and once $n^2+5n+1$ is odd (by hypothesis) and $2n+6=2(n+3)$ is even then $(n+1)^2+5(n+1)+1$ is odd.

Comment: Thank you! So this means that the given formula is always odd for any chosen natural number n?

Comment: @Garret, right!

Answer (score 2):

For $ n=1$, we get $1^2+5\cdot 1+1=7$ so we have an odd number. Now, let's suppose that $ n^2+5n+1$ is odd. We have to prove that $(n+1)^2+5 (n+1)+1$ is odd. But $(n+1)^2+5(n+1)+1=n^2+2n+1+5n+5+1=(n^2+5n+1)+2(n+3) $ which is an odd number since by hyphotesis $ n^2+5n+1$ is odd and $2(n+3) $ is even. Hence $ n^2+5n+1$ is an odd number for every $ n\in\Bbb {N} $.

Answer (score 0):

There are two cases :

> - $n$ is even or $n=2k$

then $n^2+5n+1$

$=4k^2+10k+1$

$=2(2k^2+5k)+1$

$=2K+1 \implies n$ is odd.

> - $n$ is odd or $n=2p+1$

then $n^2+5n+1$

$=(2p+1)^2+5(2p+1)+1$

$=4p^2+4p+1+10p+5+1=2(2p^2+7p+1)+1$

$=2K'+1 \implies n$ is odd.

in all cases, $n$ is odd.

Comment: @Garrett Someone downvoted for no reason.

Answer (score 0):

Saying that $n^2+5n+1$ is even is equivalent to saying $n^2+5n$ is odd. We have $n^2+5n=n(n+5)$.

$(1)\qquad n$ even $\implies n+5$ odd.

$(2)\qquad n$ odd $\implies n+5$ even

An even number times an odd number is always even, so $n^2+5n$ is always even, and thus $n^2+5n+1$ is always odd.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need induction: just use *Lil' Fermat* and congruences:
$$n^2+5n+1\equiv n+n+1=2n+1\equiv 1\mod 2.$$

If you absolutely want to use induction, here is the *inductive step*:
$$(n+1)^2+5(n+1)+1-(n^2+5n+1)=2n+6=2(n+3), $$
hence, $(n+1)^2+5(n+1)+1$ and $n^2+5n+1$ have the same parity.

Answer (score 0):

By Gauss' trick,
$$
n^2+5n+1 = 2\times (3 + 4 + \cdots + (n+2)) +1
$$
According to an unverifiable tradition, Gauss discovered when he was ten years old that he could sum the terms of an arithmetic sequence by writing the sequence once from left to right, and once from right to left. By adding the two lines, one sees that the sum of the columns are all equal, in our case this sum is $(n+5)$. As there are $n$ columns in the sum, it follows that $2S=n\times (n+5)$ 
$$
\begin{array}{cccccc}
S & = & 3 & +&4&+&\cdots &+&(n+1)&+&(n+2)\\
S & = & (n+2) & +&(n+1)&+&\cdots &+& 4&+&3\\ 
\hline 2S &=& (n+5)&+&(n+5)&+&\cdots&+&(n+5)&+&(n+5)
\\ &=& n\times(n+5)
\end{array}
$$

Comment: Maybe you should elaborate on your trick: I know that ${n+1\choose 2}=1+2+...n$, but OP might not.

Answer (score 0):

so many ways.

But if you want induction:

1) $0^2 + 5*0 + 1 = 1$ is odd.

2) If $q$ is odd, then $q + 2k$ is odd.

If $n^2 + 5n + 1$ is odd then $(n+1)^2 + 5(n+1) + 1 =$
$ n^2 + 2n + 1 + 5n + 5 + 1 = $
$n^2 + 5n + 1 + 2n + 6 = $
$n^2 + 5n + 1 +2(n+3)$ is odd.

But there are are much easier ways.  Such as:

$n^k \text{ is odd } \iff n \text { is odd }$ (assuming $k \ge 1$).

$even*n $ is always even.

$odd*n \text { is odd } \iff n \text{ is odd }$.

$odd + odd = even; odd + even = odd; even + even = even$

So... $n^2 + 5n + 1 = $
$odd/even + odd/even + odd$
$ = (odd + odd)/(even + even) + odd = even + odd$
$ = odd$.

Answer (score 0):

If $n^2+5n+1$ is odd, then $(n+1)^2+5(n+1)+1=n^2+5n+1+2n+6$ has the same parity.

Answer (score 0):

> **Hint:** The parity of $n$ is different from the parity of $n+5$.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: What does parity mean? And thank you for the hint!

Comment: @Garrett:  Parity means, e.g. the parity of $2$ is even and the parity of $7$ is odd.

Comment: @Garrett:  Similarly, the parity of $1$ is odd and the parity of $6$ is even.  Generalizing, you get $\ldots$?

Comment: Yes I understand! Thank you for explaining.